# Eclipse with PDT: How to sync project to remote server

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

I am using Eclipse with PDT for PHP development,
I have Remote Systems installed, and I work on remote files on server via SSH connection.

Is there a way to sync a local PHP project to the server like I would with Aptana for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PDT haven't such feature. You can:

1. Use rsync via command line or eclipse external program configuration
2. Use aptana together with pdt